# How to create a dataframe from dictionary with auto-increment index

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I understand to create a dataframe, i need to specify index from my dictionary, else we get the 'ValueError: if using all scalar values, you must pass an index' error.

however, how do i create a dataframe from dictionary where the index is just an auto-increment number?

Comment: IIUC then `pd.DataFrame(your_dict, index = np.arange(len(your_dict)))` should work

Comment: yep, that works, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct an index using `np.arange` and pass the `len` of your dict:

```
pd.DataFrame(your_dict, index = np.arange(len(your_dict)))
```

However, if you only have a single value as scalar values in your dict then it's more appropriate to have a single row:

```
In [165]:
d = {'a':1,'b':3}
pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])

Out[165]:
   a  b
0  1  3
```

Or you can use `from_dict` and pass `orient='index'`:

```
In [166]:
d = {'a':1,'b':3}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')

Out[166]:
   0
a  1
b  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Two steps

1. Create a pandas Series from the dictionary
   `ser = pd.Series(dictionary_here)`
2. Create a new dataframe from the Series and it's index as such

   `df1 = pd.DataFrame({"column1":ser.index, "column2":ser.values})`